# My controller is interfering with my ui-routing

Tags: angularjs

I had a working prototype of state views with hardcoded values, but when I tried to include a controller, it breaks the ui-sref links, and they don't seem to point to anything. I can remove the ng-controller attribute and they work again though, and display just fine.

I've also tried attaching ng-controller to a div in the template as well, foregoing a controller in index.html altogether, and while that doesn't break the link, I can't get any expressions in the template to work, and having a controller would be sub-optimal for the purposes of my app if I could avoid it.

What limitations of controllers and views am I misunderstanding?

index.html snippet

```
<div class="main" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <a ui-sref="StateA">AAAAA</a>
    <div ui-view></div>
</div>
```

app.js

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ui.router']);

app.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $stateProvider
        .state('StateA', {
            url: "/a",
            templateUrl: "views/a.html",
            controller: "MainCtrl"
        })
});
```

MainCtrl.js

```
app.controller("MainCtrl", [$scope, function($scope, paramGroups) {//empty controller//}]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Apart from some of the syntax errors you have going on your *fundamental* problem is understanding of how ui-router works.

When you define something like:

```
.state('StateA', {
            url: "/a",
            templateUrl: "views/a.html",
            controller: "MainCtrl"
        })
```

It means, that when you go to route `/a`  the partial `a.html` that will get rendered in your `ui-view` will get the scope for `MainCtrl`.

There's no point defining `ng-controller='MainCtrl'` on the element that is parent of `ui-view` because, `ui-view` will automatically get the scope for `MainCtrl` when the route resolves.

Route breaks when you declare that `ng-controller` because you are trying to nest same controller inside itself.